# How to find out the number of nodes in the interval of mesh

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

I have a mesh created for the femur. I need to apply a total load of 800 N in the range 480 < z < 500. To do this, I need to know the number of nodes in this interval in order to apply Force to each node/on the number of nodes. How do I find out the number of nodes in the grid for a certain interval?

Comment: You could use the "Coordinates" property of mesh1 like so `mesh1["Coordinates"] // Length`.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit: For example, what do you mean with "... in the range of 480"?

Comment: @user21 I need to know how many nodes are in the 480 < z < 500 range
not fully written

Comment: @TimLaska I don't need to know the total number of nodes, but only in the range 480 < z < 500

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you do not give a whole lot of details, code etc. This is what you asked for:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[Ball[]];
Length[Select[mesh["Coordinates"], (0.1 <= #[[3]] <= 0.2) &]]
```

> `969`

I am not convinced that this is the way to go for your problem though. But without a proper description it's hard to say what should be done.